# How to connect asp.net Identity to SQL Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

Under normal circumstances, when the registered members are connected to defaultconnection. But my database is within Azure. How to connect to SQL Azure? I tried to change the connection string, like this

```html
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=[azuresercername].database.windows.net;initial catalog=[azuredatabasename];user id=[userid];password=[userpassword];" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

It failed. So I would like to ask how to solve. Please. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the SQL Azure firewall is open for the IP address of your development machine and/or Azure resources. See the following article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Also, you need to use SSL when connecting to the server. This article walks you through getting the full connection string:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-dotnet-simple/

Comment: Yes,I had added the IP address. But it still failed.